# Error minimum when it is minimum

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $X$ be a continuous random variable with pdf $f > 0$. I need to show that $E|X-c|$ is minimum when c=median.

Now after some algebraic manipulation I have got the following expression for $$E|X-c|=2cP(X \leq c) -c +2\int_c^\infty xf(x)dx -E[X]$$

How to proceed from there ?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** Differentiate with respect to $c$. Note that

$$\frac{d}{dc} \mathbb{P}(X \leq c) =f(c)$$